# Is it possible to use a loop to create integer variables from a string array? C++

Tags: c++

For example, I have a string of dates, and I want to seperate out the days and months of each string then convert those into integers. Something like the following:

```
string dateArray[10] = {"03/02/2020", "04/02/2020", "04/02/2020", "05/02/2020", "11/02/2020"};
string date1 = dateArray[0]; 
string day1 = date1.substr(0,2);  
string mth1 = date1.substr(3,2);  
int d1 = stoi(day1);  
int m1 = stoi(mth1);
```

the result is d1 = 3 and m1 = 2.

I want to do repeat this process for a much longer array of dates, meaning if I did the above manually I would have a lot of copied code. I'm wondering if there's a better way? Thanks.

Comment: you want to use an arry for `d` and `m` too. Whenever you have variables named `d1`,d2`,d3` etc then you should consider using an array, `std::vector` for dynamic sized arrays

Comment: Are you aware of arrays/vectors? If you are please explain why they are no option.

Comment: @Yunnosch C++ arrays and vectors don't just fix everything, you first need to understand how it works on a more basic level...

Comment: @user11914177 Did you mistake my clarification question for an attempt to answer and solve the problem? I just wanted to know whether the question was caused by not knowing these constructs. September you know....

Answer (score 1):

You can use std::array and range-based loop:

```
std::array<std::string, 10> dateArray = {"03/02/2020", "04/02/2020", "04/02/2020", "05/02/2020", "11/02/2020"};
for (auto const &date : dateArray) {
    auto day1 = date.substr(0,2);  
    auto mth1 = date.substr(3,2);  
    int d1 = stoi(day1);  
    int m1 = stoi(mth1);
}
```

Beware that you specify the size of array of 10 and provide only 5 strings for initialization. The remaining 5 strings will be default constructed and will become empty strings. Which is ok. What is not ok, calling substr(3,2) on an empty string will result in an exception thrown (std::out_of_range).

You have either to make the array of size 5 `std::array<std::string,5>` or provide 10 strings to initialize it.

Comment: your code isnt "aware" of empty array elements. `substr` will throw an exception that you ignore.

Comment: Yes, sure it will! But my understanding is that elaborating in that direction goes beyond the original question. Anyway I noted in the answer about the not completely initialized array. Should have been more specific, though. Thanks!

Comment: Well this code surely does the job, but it is quite hard to understand if you are a beginner, which I think Jonny Aitken is. the range based loop, std arrays and the auto keyword aren't that obvious when you just start programming. Also at least at some point of your coding career you should have used regular for loops with a real running index....

Comment: This answer is for the (slightly) more advanced users. For the OP, we have the other answer, which uses C-style arrays and integer indices.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, really appreciate that!

Comment: btw range based for loops also work with c-arrays. Your `std::array` is nice but not necessary

Comment: How I wish std::arrays were around and widely used the time I started learning C++.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is for loops. In a for loop, you have a running index, which is a variable that is incremented a number of times.

In this array operation here: `string date1 = dateArray[0];`  you are accessing the array at element 0 and then doing your processing.
Now all you have to do is to do this for elements 0, 1, 2, 3... This is where a for loop comes in handy, it lets you use a variable, usually called i, which goes from 0 to some value you want. For your code it would look like this:

```
string dateArray[10] = {"03/02/2020", "04/02/2020", "04/02/2020", "05/02/2020", "11/02/2020"};
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    string date1 = dateArray[i]; 
    string day1 = date1.substr(0,2);  
    string mth1 = date1.substr(3,2);  
    int d1 = stoi(day1);  
    int m1 = stoi(mth1);
}
```

Notice the ten in the for loop, this should be the same as the size of your array if you want to do this operation for every element of you array